# XSL ler nomes de arquivos de uma pasta

Tags: xml, xslt

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de arquivos numa pasta:

```
-PASTA_XYZ
  - file1.xml
  - file2.xml
  - file3.xml
  - index.xml
```

Gostaria que o arquivo index.xml retornasse o nome dos arquivos dessa pasta, porém estou com dificuldades na instrução FOR-EACH:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <list>
        <xsl:for-each select="collection(.?select=*.xml')">
            a
        </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Quando eu executo o arquivo `index.xml` no *browser*, é impresso na tela somente "a", sendo que o esperado seria imprimir "aaa", uma vez que existem 3 arquivos, e o laço FOR-EACH deveria ser executado 3 vezes.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Só para lhe ajudar a se acostumar com nossa filosofia, que é diferente de um fórum, dê uma olhada em pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior, especialmente o 3o. item. Se ainda não leu, seria bom dar uma olhada em [about], você ganha uma medalha. Você pode usar o [edit] para deixar sua pergunta com o jeito de uma pergunta direta e limpa. Aos poucos você vai acostumando.

Comment: @bigown Grato pelas dicas. Gostaria de saber se essa é uma mensagem padrão de boas vindas ou existe realmente algo a ser melhorado na minha pergunta.

Comment: Ambos :) melhorei para você. Não há uma recomendação rígida do que deve ser feito em cada detalhe, mas o que estava mais fora do padrão que adotamos eram textos que agradeciam (o importante é a pergunta em si) e se alguém pode ajudar, que é retórica, nós estamos aqui para ajudar. Costumamos ser bem objetivos para ser mais fácil ajudar e para ser útil para outras pessoas.

Comment: Perfeito! Got it! Tks! :)

Comment: O browser não vai interpretar o seu documento como um XSL. A única forma de fazer isto é incluindo uma instrução de processamento `<?xml-stylesheet...>` no seu *documento XML fonte* com uma referência para o XSL. O seu documento-fonte tem XSLT mas o browser não vai interpretar. Ele está simplesmente imprimindo o nó de texto que contém `a`.

Answer (score 1):

O comportamento do browser é o *esperado*. Você incluiu um documento XML que contém a instrução de processamento `<?xml-stylesheet...>`, portanto o browser não vai mostrar a estrutura do XML como faria com documentos que não têm essa instrução (ele entrega a responsabilidade ao processador XSLT). Mas ele não acha o arquivo, e não tendo regras de estilo para formatar os tags, imprime-os usando estilos default exibindo na tela o único nó de texto que está disponível: `a`.

Simplesmente carregar um XSLT no browser não vai fazer ele ser executado porque o browser *não sabe se o documento XML em questão é um XSL*! Para o browser, você simplesmente carregou um XML qualquer. Você precisa usar a instrução de processamento `<?xml-stylesheet...>` para informar a URL de um XSLT para que o browser possa tentar interpretá-la.

O seu documento XML possui uma dessas, mas ela se refere a um documento que não existe na pasta onde você informou estarem seus arquivos:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
```

Essa instrução significa que seu documento (`index.xml`?) está sendo tratado pelo browser como um *documento-fonte* para `test.xsl`.

Vou então supor que o seu documento `index.xml` seja na verdade outro, e esse que você postou seja na verdade seu `text.xsl`. Neste caso, você deve remover a instrução de processamento e copiá-la para o seu `index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<raiz>
    <mensagem>Hello, world</mensagem>
</raiz>
```

Agora sim o browser irá tratar o código que você postou (supondo estar ele em `test.xsl`) como XSLT. Você carrega o `index.xml`, e o browser processa o `test.xsl` para transformar seu documento.

E então ele falha. Por vários motivos.

O primeiro é que é necessário ter ao menos um template numa folha de estilos XSLT. O template vai fazer correspondência com os nos da árvore XML do seu documento-fonte usando XPath. Já existem alguns templates embutidos, prontos, mas se você quiser produzir algo diferente você precisa criar um.

Isso vai depender da estrutura do seu documento-fonte. No exemplo que eu postei, você poderia escrever templates para combinar com `/` (elemento raiz), `raiz`, `mensagem`. Para rapidamente consertar o seu documento XSLT, e como não sei qual a estrutura real do seu documento-fonte, podemos incluir seu código dentro de um template que combina com `/`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <list>
            <xsl:for-each select="collection('.?select=*.xml')">
                a
            </xsl:for-each>
        </list>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Isto seria suficiente para consertar o seu XSLT. Agora você pode carregar o `index.xml` e o processador XSLT do browser irá processar o template, gerando uma lista. Mas não vai funcionar porque quase certamente seu browser **não suporta XSLT 2.0**. E não adianta mudar o `version` porque a função `collection()` só existe em XSLT 2.0.

Existem várias alternativas, porém. Você pode pegar a lista de arquivos de outro lugar, do próprio arquivo-fonte, de um outro arquivo externo, e usar a função `document()` que existe em XSLT 1.0. Mas o ideal é você estudar um pouco mais sobre XPath e XSLT antes, pois o uso dessas funções não é tão trivial.

Se o seu arquivo-fonte (`index.xml`) tivesse uma seção contendo os nomes dos arquivos que você precisa carregar, por exemplo:

```
<raiz>
    ...
    <arquivos>
        <arquivo>file1.xml</arquivo>
        <arquivo>file2.xml</arquivo>
        <arquivo>file3.xml</arquivo>
    </arquivos>
</raiz>
```

Você poderia usar a instrução abaixo para imprimir uma lista contendo o nome do elemento raiz de cada um deles:

```
<list>
    <xsl:for-each select="document(//arquivo)">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="name(./*)"/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</list>
```

Isto `funciona` em XSLT 1.0. Então você pode mudar o `version` para `1.0` e testar em qualquer browser moderno.